# "I don't think we should go to the movie tomorrow" - what does it mean actually?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, negation

I don't think we should go to the movie tomorrow.

Does it actually mean: We shouldn't go to the movie tomorrow?

Comment: Which part of the sentence is not clear?

Comment: When people say that it usually means "I don't want to go to the movie tomorrow."

Answer (score 8):

Almost. It means "*I think* we shouldn't go to the movie tomorrow."

Comment: One of my teachers used to get angry about constructions like that. "No, no, it doesn't necessarily mean you think we shouldn't! The fact that you're not thinking something DOES NOT mean that you're thinking the opposite!" Lovely stuff.

Comment: What do you mean 'what does it mean actually?'  There is no hidden meaning to the sentence.